# autosum in pdf file

Tags: php, actionscript-3

I want to get auto sum in the pdf, for example, when I tick checkbox, it will automatically calculate the sum of ticked box.

Here is my code:

```
if($books){
$i=1;
foreach($books as $b){
    if($b->code){
        $bodyContent .= '<tr><td>'.$i.'</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="g'.$i.'" value="0" /></td><td><input type="checkbox" name="d'.$i.'" value="0" /></td><td><input type="checkbox" name="u'.$i.'" value="0" /></td><td>'.$u->code.': '.$u->name.'</td></tr>';
        $i++;
    }
}
$bodyContent .= '<tr><td></td><td><input type="text" name="g_total" size="3" /></td><td><input type="text" name="d_total" size="3" /></td><td><input type="text" name="u_total" size="3" /></td><td>Totals</td></tr>';
```

Comment: How does this relate to actionscript?  I'm so confused.... I see php outputting HTML and you're talking about a PDF? how does this all relate?

Comment: the code I paste here is the content of pdf